# Error: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

What does this mean?  I have been fighting with this `ListView` that I have using an `ArrayAdapter`.  I wrote this nice dialog fragment that I have calling back to an updateUI listner cause I want to update this `ListView` I have in my fragment from the `DialogFragment` at first the `ArrayAdapter` was a complex type of a class i Created:

```
ArrayAdapter<Location> theLocations;
...
//in oncreateview
theLocations = new ArrayAdapter<Location>(mContext, R.layout.location_row, locations);
//here locations is an ArrayList<Location>
```

then I have:

```
public void onUIUpdate(Location l) { //called from dialog fragment      
 locations.add(l);                  
 theLocations.notifyDataSetChanged();       
}
```

then that gave the above error so I switched it to use just a

```
String[] locationNames = new String[sizeofLocations];
theLocations=new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, R.layout.location_Row, locationNames );

public void onUIUpdate(Location l) {        
    locations.add(l);                   
            locationNames = new String[locations.size()];
            for(locations.size() etc...) { 
               locationNames [i] = new String(locations.get(i).getName());
            }
    theLocations.notifyDataSetChanged();        
}
```

this didn't error out in my update method (That updates the ui) but it didn't update anything. So I am lost as to how to update this ArrayAdapter, I thought notifyChange was supposed to do it, but it either does nothing or throws the above error.

I have no issues with my SimpleCursorAdapters elsewhere in my program (As long as my cursors remain open and i call a requery on them).

Any insights into what I am doing wrong?

Upon request here is my layout for the R.layout.location_row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"     android:orientation="horizontal">   
<TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/location_name"
    android:textSize="15px" android:layout_marginTop="10px" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
<TextView android:text="|" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="15px" android:layout_marginTop="6px" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
<TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/location_lat"
    android:textSize="15px" android:layout_marginTop="6px" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
<TextView android:text="|$" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="15px" android:layout_marginTop="6px" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>  
<TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/location_lon"
    android:textSize="15px" android:layout_marginTop="6px" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your R.layout.location_row XML file, please?

Comment: done, I realize that the error is claiming it cannot set a TextView to something else (Probably my Location type of complexClass) though I suspected the overriding of toString would of taken care of that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As we can read in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html
ArrayAdapter just works with strings on textviews. You can use this constructor

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
```

specifyng the id of a TextView inside your layout or override

```
getView(int, View, ViewGroup)
```

returning a view of your custom type.

Comment: really stupid question then, where do i override the getView? Do I have to extend ArrayAdapter?

Comment: I think is ussual to extend BaseAdapter class

Comment: Is this basically creating a CustomAdapter?

Comment: Yes, a custom adapter that extends BaseAdapter. On getView() you can inflate your layout and return it.