# ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Tags: java, android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="22px"
        android:layout_height="22px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:layout_marginTop="4px"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20px" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The above is my layoutm "`messages.xml`"

```
public class TabClass extends ListFragment {    

    @Override
      public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        String[] values = new String[] { "label1", "label2", "label3"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.messages, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
      }

      @Override
      public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Do something with the data

      }

}
```

I get this error when i try to compile the application `"ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280965/arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-textview-xml-problems

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673829/arrayadapter-requires-id-to-be-a-textview-error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822632/error-arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-textview

Comment: @baraky consider to post a single comment with all your links :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your messages.xml contains a LinearLayout with ImageView and TextView. Instead, it should just contain a TextView. See the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20T%5B%5D%29). Your ArrayAdapter constructor's second parameter takes :

> The resource ID for a layout file containing a TextView to use when
> instantiating views.

Hint: You might want to create a custom adapter class (which extends BaseAdapter) instead of the ArrayAdapter class.